# send mail through bcc

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

how can i send mass mail through bcc in asp.net(c#)..??

Comment: Can you remove the sql tag please it's not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx) you do it like this:

```
public static void CreateBccTestMessage(string server)
{
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
message.Body = @"Using this feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("manager1@contoso.com");
message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
Console.WriteLine("Sending an e-mail message to {0} and {1}.", 
           to.DisplayName, message.Bcc.ToString());
  try {
    client.Send(message);
  }  
  catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateBccTestMessage(): {0}", 
                ex.ToString() );
  }
}
```

You just add several bcc addresses. Note that sending mass mails will easily get you blacklisted and most of your messages will probably end up in spam folders. You should consider using a mass mail service provider for this instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you of the System.Net.Mail namespace classes for send out mails in .net applications. Refer to MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx